# python script -- writing logs to different places depending how it's being run

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

is there any way to get a python script to write logs to 2 different locations: file and terminal? But it should only print logs to the terminal if I run it manually. Othwervise when it's run by something else, it should only write logs to a log file. is it possible at all?

Comment: check if this helps you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957734/start-python-script-with-cron-and-output-print-to-a-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking for interactive shell in a Python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108330/checking-for-interactive-shell-in-a-python-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the isatty() method that returns True if your program is connected to a tty, else it returns False. So in your case you could code something like this:

```
import sys

if sys.stdin.isatty():
   # Logs put here will be displayed on terminal when you invoke the script via cli
else:
    with open("/testFile.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write('Logging in a file')
```